# how to check if style changed color

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to detect when a style has changed color in my webBrowser, I've got this code in a button when clicked it should check for a changed color but it dont work for some reason

```
Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All
        For Each webpageelemnt As HtmlElement In allelements
            If webpageelemnt.GetAttribute("style") = "color: red;" Then
                MessageBox.Show("New inbox")

            Else
```

button from site which turns red when got a new inbox

```
<a href="#" class="messages topadclick animated seeMePlease" title="Inbox" onclick="getInbox(); return false;" style="color: red;">
        '<i Class="icon-envelope icon-2x"></i>
        '</a>
```

could any one shed some light on what i'm missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals()` to test strings. Also I'd use `.contains()` because it may happend that the style attribute contains more rules.

Try using this test:

```
If webpageelemnt.GetAttribute("style").contains("color: red;") Then
    [...]
```

Another thought: are you sure that your html element gets caught in your loop? 
Are you watching the value of  `webpageelemnt.GetAttribute("style")` with the debugger?

Comment: ive tried both ways still not detecting that style change, ive checked debugger but im kinda new to this but from what i can see its returning nothing so unsure on what to do next , site is chatib dot com if u wanna have a look .I just need to check for when i get a new message (Inbox)

Comment: In this case, did you check that WebBrowser1.Document.All returns something at all?